# Install app with enterprise app url scheme

Tags: ios, url, enterprise

Can we install iOS app with enterprise app url scheme and Url identifier

install app without sighing and with same Url identifier with first signed enterprise app

I dont want to add every app id on developer panel
and I want to use inhouse distrubiotion